# How can i repeat this script many times

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, browser-automation

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
time.sleep(2.5)
driver.refresh()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the script, putting code in a loop:

```
def submit_form():

   driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
   time.sleep(2.5)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
   time.sleep(2.5)
   driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
   time.sleep(2.5)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
   time.sleep(2.5)
   driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
   time.sleep(2.5)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
   time.sleep(2.5)
   driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
   time.sleep(2.5)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
   time.sleep(2.5)
   driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
   time.sleep(2.5)
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
   time.sleep(2.5)
   driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
   time.sleep(2.5)
   driver.refresh()

[submit_form() for _ in range(0,5)] #Run the submit_form function 5 times
```

Comment: i tried the above code it doesnt work

Comment: @pocketmonster give us more details. What does "it doesnt work" mean? It runs the code only for a single time or it throws exception?